# Искать все русские буквы кроме указанных

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой код:

```
var arr = "аа, бб, вв, гг, дд, ЕЕ, рр, шш";
arr.match(/[а-я]+/gu);
```

Результат такой:

```
["аа", "бб", "вв", "гг", "дд", "рр", "шш"]
```

Хочу делать так, чтобы исключались некоторые русские буквы, например, буква `р`, или чтобы исключалось целое слово.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Перечислить нужные, а ненужные на перечислять.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В JavaScript можно использовать блок просмотра вперёд:

```js
var arr = "аа, бб, вв, гг, дд, ЕЕ, рр, шш";
console.log(arr.match(/(?:(?![рР])[а-яА-ЯёЁ])+/g));
```

`(?:(?![рР])[а-яА-ЯёЁ])+` — 1 и более повторов буквы, которая находится с помощью символьного класса `[а-яА-ЯёЁ]`, но не находится с помощью `[рР]`.